# Understanding Django's directory structure

Tags: django

After a few months of Rails, I'm trying to learn Django this time.
The following directory structure seems inefficient to me.
For example, if you're making a `poll` application, the structure will be like this.

`mainproject/polls/templates/polls`

Why cant it be instead

`mainproject/polls/templates/`?

For me, it's become

`my-django-projects/blog/blog/templates/blog/`

first `blog` = project name, second `blog` = app name, third `blog` = directory inside templates folder.

Is this a reasonable structure?

Answer (score 0):

The following template directory pattern is correct. It is recommended to save application related template files in the application directory.

```
mainproject/polls/templates/
```

However you can define your template directory at project level by defining TEMPLATE_DIRS in your setting file.

```
mainproject/templates/polls
```

[Customizing template dirs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial02/#ref-customizing-your-projects-templates)

[Example rendering an application template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a problem with the structure `mainproject/templates/`, if you creates your app only for your project, go ahead with this form.

The other way (`mainproject/polls/templates/polls/`) is mainly used when you plan to develop the app independent of your project, so you will distribute it to use (maybe by other peoples) in others projects, so is a best practice to left theirs a couple of template to see how your app works and then create their owns templates in the project by customizing your app templates to suit their needs.

The repeated app name should sound superfluous, but there are a reason for it, django search template files in the `template` directory of apps and project, see the following structure:

```
mainproject
|-- poll
|   |-- templates
|       |-- index.html
|
|-- blog
    |-- templates
        |-- index.html
```

When django tries to loads index.html it will choose the first name match, so the template maybe not shown correctly for the app requested. Then a way to be sure to load the right template is to create another directory and for convenience use the name of the app, in this way:

```
mainproject
|-- poll
|   |-- templates
|       |-- poll
|           |-- index.html
|
|-- blog
    |-- templates
        |-- blog
            |-- index.html
```

So the last eliminate the ambiguity, since you need to specify `'blog/index.html'` to load the blog's index.html template